# SWT table with fixed height

Tags: java, swt

I have a simple SWT table like this, with an initial height of 60px:

```
Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
GridData gd_table = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
gd_table.heightHint = 60;
table.setLayoutData(gd_table);
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
```

I'm programmatically adding rows, when a new row is added the height of the table is increased messing with the rest of the UI, is there a way to set a fixed height to the table and maybe adding a scrollbar when the rows doesn't fit the table height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the `Table` to fill up the available vertical space, then tell the `GridData` not to do it:

```
GridData gd_table = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 2, 1);
```

should do it.

---

As for the scrollbar, simply add `SWT.V_SCROLL` to the style of the `Table`.

Comment: Please also note, that using fixed pixel hints is usually not a good idea. It may look good on the platform and OS zoom level you're using but may look awefully wrong on another plarform or another OS zoom level (hi-dpi screen for example).

Comment: Doesn't work for me... The table height is still increased but the scroll bar is missing now (although I added `SWT.V_SCROLL` to the table).